# Find something in column A then show the value of B for that row in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Basically my problem is that I have a string in one cell in excel, I then need to see if that string exists in another row (not one cell but the whole row) and if so then print the contents of another cell in the same row but in another column.

I will give a basic example:

```
Title      Answer
Police       15
Ambulance    20
Fire         89
```

Now I need to scan the title column for, say, "Police" and then populate the cell with the value under Answer (in this case 15).

I cant just say `IF(A2="Police";B2;""` as I need the scan the whole of the Title column.

I have tried using `IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A$100;"Police");` which scans the contents of A2 to A100 for the string Police, and know how to make it print a constant (just put something after the ;) but cant work out how to make that "constant" a variable that changes depending on the found row. So if the `COUNTIF` found Police in cell `A44` then the answer to my formula would be `B44`, the same as if it found Police in `A62` then my formula should show `B62`

I hope this makes sense and that someone can help me :)

Note that I am using excel 2010 and need a normal formula as I can not use scripting for this document.

EDIT:

Here is what I have so far, note that the spreadsheet I am using is far more complex than the "simple" example I have in the question...

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("RuhrP";F9));LOOKUP(A9;Ruhrpumpen!A$5:A$100;Ruhrpumpen!I$5:I$100);"")
```

This is showing `"RuhrP"` in every answer where `"RuhrP"` is found in `F9` and not the answer I want which should be that found in `RuhrPumpen!I$5:I$100` where the cell index is the same as that for the `A` coloum where `A9` was found. Again, sorry for the complexity I cant think of any better way to word it.

Comment: Are the titles unique? Then VLOOKUP seems to be the right solution: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php

Comment: Yes the values are unique but unfortunatley VLOOKUP does not work :( I have found a part solution but it is not finished yet, it involves combining IF, ISNUMBER, FIND and LOOKUP. Will update my question when I can get it working properly.

Comment: Please share the example spreadsheet & the reason why `VLOOKUP` cannot work?

Comment: Does "cell index" mean a code for a certain item?

Comment: By "Cell Index" I simply meant that if my result is found in A5 then the answer I need is in B5.
Unfortunatley I am unable to post the actual spreadsheet as it is highly confidential, I also cant post part of it as I have no time to make it :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I note you suggested this formula

`=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("RuhrP";F9));LOOKUP(A9;Ruhrpumpen!A$5:A$100;Ruhrpumpen!I$5:I$100);"")`

.....but `LOOKUP` isn't appropriate here because I assume you want an exact match (LOOKUP won't guarantee that and also data in lookup range has to be sorted), so `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX/MATCH` would be better....and you can also use IFERROR to avoid the IF function, i.e

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A9;Ruhrpumpen!A$5:Z$100;9;0);"")`

Note: VLOOKUP always looks up the lookup value (A9) in the first column of the "table array" and returns a value from the nth column of the "table array" where n is defined by col_index_num, in this case 9

INDEX/MATCH is sometimes more flexible because you can explicitly define the lookup column and the return column (and return column can be to the left of the lookup column which can't be the case in VLOOKUP), so that would look like this:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Ruhrpumpen!I$5:I$100;MATCH(A9;Ruhrpumpen!A$5:A$100;0));"")`

INDEX/MATCH also allows you to more easily return multiple values from different columns, e.g. by using $ signs in front of A9 and the lookup range Ruhrpumpen!A$5:A$100, i.e.

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Ruhrpumpen!I$5:I$100;MATCH($A9;Ruhrpumpen!$A$5:$A$100;0));"")`

this version can be dragged across to get successive values from column I, column J, column K etc.....

Comment: Barry Houdini, I tried your answer onto a similiar question that I had. It returns the correct value. However, it is returning only the first matching value. If I want it to return all matching data in a column, how can I do that? Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 1):

Assuming

source data range is A1:B100.
query cell is D1 (here you will input Police or Fire).
result cell is E1

Formula in E1 = `VLOOKUP(D1, A1:B100, 2, FALSE)`

Comment: TY for your answer it pushed me in the right direction however my problem is not solved. Due to the complexity of what I am trying to do (my question was a VERY basic example and not complete at all) a simply VLOOKUP wont work (I dont think).
I have updated my question with my current formula and the answer I have atm.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out such data design:

Main sheet:
Column A: Pump codes (numbers)

Column B: formula showing a corresponding row in sheet 'Ruhrpumpen'

```
=ROW(Pump_codes)+MATCH(A2;Ruhrpumpen!$I$5:$I$100;0)
```

Formulae have ";" instead of ",", it should be also German notation. If not, pleace replace.

Column C: formula showing data in 'Ruhrpumpen' column A from a row found by formula in col B

```
=INDIRECT("Ruhrpumpen!A"&$B2)
```

Column D: formula showing data in 'Ruhrpumpen' column B from a row found by formula in col B:

```
=INDIRECT("Ruhrpumpen!B"&$B2)
```

Sheet 'Ruhrpumpen':

Column A: some data about a certain pump

Column B: some more data

Column I: pump codes. Beginning of the list includes defined name 'Pump_codes' used by the formula in column B of the main sheet.

Spreadsheet example: http://www.bumpclub.ee/~jyri_r/Excel/Data_from_other_sheet_by_code_row.xls

Comment: It's possible to combine formula in column B to other formulae using the row number, but I'd prefer a clearly visible reference to find data quickly.

Comment: Pretty similar to what I have. I will take it home with me tonight and make a real example spreadsheet. For some reason using a comma does not work in my formula's only a semi-colon works.

Comment: @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose Using comma or semi-colon in formulas depends on the language settings in your computer. If your Excel formulas only accept semi-colons, then that means your language settings uses comma as separator for decimal points.

Comment: @AmirSyafrudin Sounds right, I have no control over my computer settings and am forced to use the Norwegian settings even though I am English and work only in English (some auto-correct settings are extreamly annoying and cant be changed either lol).

Answer (score 0):

Guys Its very interesting to know that many of us face the problem of replication of lookup value while using the Vlookup/Index with Match or Hlookup.... If we have duplicate value in a cell we all know, Vlookup will pick up against the first item would be matching in loopkup array....So here is solution for you all...

e.g.

in Column A we have field called company....

```
Column A                             Column B            Column C

Company_Name                         Value        
Monster                              25000                              
Naukri                               30000  
WNS                                  80000  
American Express                     40000  
Bank of America                      50000  
Alcatel Lucent                       35000  
Google                               75000  
Microsoft                            60000  
Monster                              35000  
Bank of America                      15000
```

Now if you lookup the above dataset, you would see the duplicity is in Company Name at Row No# 10 & 11. So if you put the vlookup, the data will be picking up which comes first..But if you use the below formula, you can make your lookup value Unique and can pick any data easily without having any dispute or facing any problem

Put the formula in C2.........`A2&"_"&COUNTIF(A2:$A$2,A2)`..........Result will be `Monster_1` for first line item and for row no 10 & 11.....`Monster_2, Bank of America_2` respectively....Here you go now you have the unique value so now you can pick any data easily now..

Cheers!!!
Anil Dhawan